# Use of Signal to Noise Ratio to compare Ridge Regression Estimators

Tags: model-selection, signal-processing, ridge-regression

On p170 of Gruber's "Regression Estimators" 2010, he shows that the Liu estimator has a smaller bias than the ordinary ridge regressor but also a larger variance. So when the signal to noise ratio is compared i.e. (Bias)^2/Variance the Liu estimator has a lower signal to noise ratio.

However this seems odd to me, choosing the signal to noise ratio calculated this way will encourage you towards picking models with larger biases assuming they have same variance or smaller than the competing model?

Is this the normal way to look at signal to noise ratios when comparing ridge regression estimators?

I mean if you have an OLS estimate (and assuming no multicollinearity) there would be no bias and it would have the lowest variance? Yet it would have a signal to noise ratio of zero??

Comment: Using this metric to compare models strikes me as odd, as well.  However,   an OLS estimate would typically still have some model bias, unless the modeled function was truly linear in the predictors.